# How to get gradient bottom navigation tab in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-bottomnavigation

There is a package on **pub**
https://pub.dev/packages/gradient_bottom_navigation_bar

but this is not updated for a very long time.
So, is there a way to create own custom navigation bar with a gradient effect?

something like this...
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All it's  possible with Flutter, one option could be use a transparent background in your BottomNavigationBar and put it inside a container with a BoxDecoration, try the next:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Hello"),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: _createBottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _createBottomNavigationBar() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF00D0E1), Color(0xFF00B3FA)],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.topRight,
          stops: [0.0, 0.8],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
        onTap: (index) {},
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        elevation: 0,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text(
              "Home",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text(
              "Business",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text(
              "School",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: BottomNavigationBarItem only has the following properties . Where did you get title from ?

`const BottomNavigationBarItem({
    required this.icon,
    this.label,
    Widget? activeIcon,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.tooltip,
`

Comment: Just for reference, this solution doesn't work with BottomNavigationBarType.shifting.

Comment: The solution doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a more basic solution. You can check [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=5f2cbd1b52464cf06d199ba6607eaa73).

The end result:

[image: gradient bottom navigation bar in flutter]

The trick is this:

- Set the background color of `BottomNavigationBar` as transparent.
- Wrap it with `Stack`.
- Add a `Container` as first child to the `Stack`.
- Set `Container`'s decoration to gradient.
- Set its height to 60.

Comment: Just for reference, this solution doesn't work with BottomNavigationBarType.shifting.